# Pegar id do produto com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código `html`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando ele clicar em excluir na `div excluir-produto-carrinho` ele deve pegar o id do *data-id-prod-carrinho*. Como que eu faço isso?

Já tentei no botão excluir que é a `div excluir-produto-carrinho` assim:

```
var idStorage = $(this).data('id-prod-carrinho');
```

e não dá em nada. Tipo ele não traz nada.

Answer (score 5):

Não esta dando certo porque não é parte de $(this), é preciso navegar:

```
var idStorage = $(this)
        .closest('.prodmostra')
        .find('.imagem-prod')
        .data('id-prod-carrinho');
```

Comment: Ok deu certo. Muito obrigado